# php mysql select with different values

Tags: php, html, select

I have a table with exercises and I want to generate I want that the visitor can select the number of exercises that him wants... every exercise must be appear in a different select and I need that the first value in every select will be different. I have this code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="wod_auto_sartu.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 12);
shuffle($numbers);
for ($i=1;$i<=$num_jornadas;$i++){
    $numbers2=$numbers[$i];
    $random_wod=$wod[$numbers2];
?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inpuName" class="col-md-4 control-label"><font color="#fff"><b><?php echo _("Jornada: $i"); ?></b></font></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control  c-square c-theme" id="wod" style="opacity: .8;max-width:80%;" name="num_jornadas" method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($numbers as $row){
        echo '<option value='. $random_wod[0] .'>'. $random_wod[1] .'</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
        </div>
   </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

In this moment, I get info as I have mentioned, but if I unfold the select I get the same value in all options, I need as I said that the first option in every option will different  but when I unfold, I need see all other exercises, not the same...

How can I solve it?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bZvR.png)

Comment: You're putting the same `$wod[$numbers2][0]` in all the options. Maybe it should be `$wod[$numbers2][$n]`? BTW, why don't you like to use `foreach()` to iterate over an array?

Comment: BTW, array indexes normally start from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: The first, the second or both?

Comment: All numerically-indexed arrays normally start at 0.

Comment: I have changed the code, but the same problem, and not, [0] is the only position with data inside array.

Comment: You should post the correct code as an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! I had an error of concept... I was introducing the same array all the time waiting for a different output ... as Einstein said... "Stupidity is repeating the same error expecting different results"

The correct code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="wod_auto_sartu.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$lista_wods = array();
foreach($wod as $row=>$value):
$lista_wods[] = '<option value="'.$row.'">' .$value[1].'</option>';
endforeach;

$numbers = range(1, 12);
shuffle($numbers);
for ($i=1;$i<=$num_jornadas;$i++){
    $numbers2=$numbers[$i];
    $random_wod=$wod[$numbers2];
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inpuName" class="col-md-4 control-label"><font color="#fff"><b><?php echo _("Jornada: $i"); ?></b></font></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control  c-square c-theme" id="wod" style="opacity: .8;max-width:80%;" name="num_jornadas" method="post">
<?php
       print_r ('<option value='. $random_wod[0] .'>'. $random_wod[1] . '</option>');
       print_r(array_values($lista_wods));
?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks to those who have tried to help me!